# scp to google cloud-shell fails (ssh works)

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, scp, google-cloud-shell

I'm trying to use scp to copy a large file over to cloud shell.

Using the suggested command from this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49515502/1378902)

```
gcloud alpha cloud-shell scp \
  localhost:~/Sites/my-app/big_file cloudshell:~/big_file
```

But even though I can see it adding a key for the server, it fails with `Permission denied (publickey).`

If I do

```
gcloud alpha cloud-shell ssh
```

it logs in to the server just fine

Answer (score 2):

Turns out google's invocation of `scp` was omitting the correct username.

**Solution**
I successfully uploaded by doing

```
/usr/bin/scp -P 6000 -i /Users/me/.ssh/google_compute_engine -o \
  StrictHostKeyChecking=no ~/Sites/my-app/bigfile \ 
  cj@35.185.184.136:~/big_file
```

**How to figure this out**

I was able to discover this using the `--verbosity debug` flag

```
# gcloud alpha cloud-shell scp --verbosity debug localhost:~/Sites/my-app/big_file cloudshell:~/big_file
    DEBUG: Running [gcloud.alpha.cloud-shell.scp] with arguments: [(cloudshell|localhost):DEST: "cloudshell:~/big_file", (cloudshell|localhost):SRC:1: "['localhost:~/Sites/my-app/big_file']", --verbosity: "debug"]
    DEBUG: Running command [/usr/bin/scp -P 6000
      -i /Users/chrisjensen/.ssh/google_compute_engine
      -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no
      ~/Sites/my-app/big_file 35.185.184.136:~/big_file].
[...more debug info...]
```

^ This is the line that shows the command that was run

Then I ran `ssh` to see if there was a difference in the arguments

```
gcloud alpha cloud-shell ssh --verbosity debug
DEBUG: Running [gcloud.alpha.cloud-shell.ssh] with arguments: [--verbosity: "debug"]
DEBUG: Running command [/usr/bin/ssh -t -p 6000
  -i /Users/chrisjensen/.ssh/google_compute_engine
  -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no cj@127.0.0.1].
[...more debug info...]
```

^ Notice it prepends by username to the server ip.

So then I copied the scp command and added my username, and it worked a charm.

Hope this helps others trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

This should be fixed in the latest version of gcloud, which you can get by runnign `gcloud components update`. Thanks for trying the alpha!